# Scrollto no working in Chrome & Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

In chrome & opera no working function scrollto.
In firefox working. I don't know in what a problem. Thanks for help.

```
function scroll_to_word(){
 var pos = $('.content .selectHighlight').position();
 $.scrollTo(".selectHighlight", 500, {offset:-50});
 }

$('#search_text').bind('keyup oncnange', function() {
 $('.content').removeHighlight();
 txt = $('#search_text').val();
 if (txt == '') return;
 $('.content').highlight(txt);
 search_count = $('.content span.highlight').size() - 1;
 count_text = search_count + 1;
 search_number = 0;
 $('.content').selectHighlight(search_number);
 if ( search_count >= 0 ) scroll_to_word();
 $('#count').html('Найдено: <b>'+count_text+'</b>');
 });

$('#clear_button').click(function() {
 $('.content').removeHighlight();
 $('#search_text').val('поиск по странице');
 $('#count').html('');
 });
```

Comment: which version of scrollTo are you using?

Comment: scrollTo version 1.4.2

Comment: see https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/issues/101 - update to 2.0 is recommended

Comment: @Jaromanda X thanks! fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
keyup oncnange
```

should be:

```
keyup onchange
```